# AngularJS bind scope to html after ajax load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

After reading about it I understand that the html loaded through ajax is not bind to my angular app. I've tried 1.000 things but can't get 'customers-invoice.html' to understand angular. Any ideas will be much appreciated.

```
<body ng-cloak ng-app="myApp">
    <main id="main">
        <div ng-controller='Ctrl'>
            <a ng-click="openInvoice(data.invoiceRef)" class="btn">View</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.invoice = {}
    $scope.openInvoice = function(ref) { 
        $scope.invoice.ref = ref;
        var html = $('#main');
        html.load('customers-invoice.html')
        $compile(html)($scope);          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-include` directive in this case, it will do load html in that specified DOM with compiled DOM bindings ready for you. But since you want to get bindings of your `Ctrl` controller, you have to put that DOM it inside `Ctrl` controller `div`

```
<body ng-cloak ng-app="myApp">
    <main id="main">
        <div ng-controller='Ctrl'>
            <a ng-click="openInvoice(data.invoiceRef)" class="btn">View</a>
            <div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.openInvoice = function(ref) { 
    $scope.invoice.ref = ref;
    $scope.templateUrl = 'customers-invoice.html';     
}
```

Comment: I finally opted for this solution since it uses angular's own methods. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) service to load the html file to the controller because the template is already loaded into the cache.

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $compile, $templateRequest, $sce) {
     $scope.invoice = {}
     $scope.openInvoice = function(ref) {
         var templateUrl = $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl('customers-invoice.html');

         $templateRequest(templateUrl).then(function(template) {
             $compile($("#main").html(template).contents())($scope);
         });
     }
 })
```

Comment: Thanks, but still cant render the modified scope

Comment: its working, make sure to add jquery lib. https://plnkr.co/edit/bpBXDi7PC7gYBOgz3h0Y?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I have a better solution now! Instead of using $.ajax, just use $http (which i imagine it runs the digest cycle for you behind the scenes). Anyway, problem solved!

here is the link to the angulajs page explaining how to use $http
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

Ive finally manaed to underestand better the problem and solve it accordingly.
Because we are executing code outside of Angular's knowledge, we need to compile the inserted html for it to see Angular, and then manually call $scope.$digest() to update the markup.

So this just does the trick:

$compile($('#idWhereIloadedContent').contents())($scope);

$scope.$digest();